# How to convert a for loop into an apply method in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, apply

I am trying to change this for loop into an apply method because iterrows/itertuples are both too slow. I have a pretty big data set. Is this possible?

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    startDateString = str(row['Date'].replace("/",""))
    endDateString = str(row['Date'].replace("/",""))
    zipcode = str(row['Zip'])
    #startDateString = str(startDate)
    #endDateString = str(endDate)
    print("zip: " + "%s" %zipcode + ", daterange: " + startDateString + " - " + endDateString )
```

Comment: what’s the goal here, just to print something to screen?

Comment: I am using the loop information to plug into an API call.

Comment: `.apply` won't be significantly faster than `itertuples`. In general, text-processing is slow with `pandas`, but you can try to use vectorized operations (although, the advantages of vectorization aren't much with str data)

Answer (score 0):

Why are startDate and endDate the same column?

The str calls are useless as the format specifer does them. Removing them results in:

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    startDate = row['Date'].replace("/","")
    endDate = row['Date'].replace("/","")
    zipcode = row['Zip']
    print("zip: %s, daterange: %s - %s" % (zipcode, startDate, endDate))
```

Comment: For this instance - I am using these values to plug into an API call and I need the start and end dates to be the same. And thank you I will remove the str calls.

Answer (score -1):

apply() is one of the slowest methods in the pandas library.  You can do the same thing with str attribute calls.
You don't need to create all the variables.

```
    df2['new_column'] = f"""zip: {df2.Zip}, daterange: {df2['Date'].str.replace("/","")} - {df2['Date'].str.replace("/","")}"""
    for x in df2.new_column:
         print(x)
```

Hope this works with your data.

Comment: F-strings? Should preface this requires at least a specific Python version.

Comment: Use Python 3.6 because f-strings are awesome and so are the new dictionary speeds.